# Plot scatter/line plot with distribution in the upper right corner in Matplotlib or Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

`seaborn` has a wonderful feature of [`jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html)s combining scatter/line plot with marginal distributions on the sides. However, I have not found a way how to do it along the main diagonal. An example of that can be found in this [article](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2019.12.29.890319v1.full) (DOI: 10.1101/2019.12.29.890319) as [Fig. 4](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/early/2019/12/31/2019.12.29.890319/F4.large.jpg?width=800&height=600&carousel=1) which is a bit of an extreme but would be enough if there was an option to get the distribution along the 1-3 quadrant (or 2-4 quadrant). Is there a way how to do it with `seaborn` or `matplotlib`?

Comment: This is doable but not easy, see [here](https://gist.github.com/LegrandNico/2b201863dc7ae28d568573c66047dd86) for one example.

Comment: Hi @mwaskom, I realised that it's not easy when I was trying to write it :D. I did not know about that link, thanks a lot. Have you thought of implementing/adding it to seaborn?